# I am performing web scraping on influenster.com but I am not able to scrape the star rating

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, data-science, scrape

The link I am using is https://www.influenster.com/reviews/loreal-paris-elvive-extraordinary-oil-deep-nourishing-shampoo-and-conditioner-set-126-fl-oz. Please guide me on how I can get the stars as there is no aria label or numerical value to scrape.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import configparser
from datetime import datetime

parser = configparser.RawConfigParser()
parser.read('config.ini')

url= parser['PROPERTIES']['URL']
END_DATE = datetime.strptime(parser['DATE']['END'], '%Y-%m-%d')
START_DATE=datetime.strptime(parser['DATE']['START'],'%Y-%m-%d')
# Setting up driver options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# Setting up Path to chromedriver executable file
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH =r'C:\Users\HP\Desktop\INTERNSHIP\influenster\chromedriver.exe'
# Adding options
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
# Setting up chrome service
service = ChromeService(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH)
# Establishing Chrom web driver using set services and options
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get(url)
# The 2 lines below is what I actually added here + necessary imports
# and `wait` object initialization   
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
reviews = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".conversations-left .item")))
count=0
item_list = []

for review in reviews:
    item={  
         #stars     
        'username': review.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'name')]").text,
        'userurl':review.find_element_by_xpath(".//a[contains(@class,'name')]").get_attribute("href"),
        'title': 'NA',
        # 'review_text':review.find_element_by_xpath(".//div[contains(@class,'review-text')]").text,
        #  'permalink': 'NA',
        #  'date':curr_date,
        #  'subproduct name': 'NA',
        #  'subproduct link': 'NA',
}
    item_list.append(item)
print(item_list)
```

Comment: What stars are you trying to scrape? There are several: main product rating, other products ratings, reviews ratings...

Comment: Also, please share your code otherwise this question will be closed. It's not me, these are rules here...

Comment: user reviews only and not the ones present in question and answers section

Comment: I see stars there without ratings. So actually nothing to scrape...

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of achieving your stated goal (get the product star rating):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
actions = ActionChains(browser)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://www.influenster.com/reviews/loreal-paris-elvive-extraordinary-oil-deep-nourishing-shampoo-and-conditioner-set-126-fl-oz'
browser.get(url) 
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click()
    print('accepted cookies')
except Exception as e:
    print('no cookie button!')
stars = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//h1/following-sibling::div/following-sibling::div/div')))
actions.move_to_element(stars).perform()
print('moved to stars')
star_rating = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(text(),"out of 5 stars")]')))
print(star_rating.text)
```

Result in terminal:

```
accepted cookies
moved to stars
4.5 out of 5 stars
```

Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

EDIT: In case you want the stars for each individual review, that's not doable with Selenium, sadly. Happily, it is doable with other method:

```
import cloudscraper
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from tqdm import tqdm

headers = {'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
           'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8',
           'referer': 'https://www.influenster.com/reviews/loreal-paris-elvive-extraordinary-oil-deep-nourishing-shampoo-and-conditioner-set-126-fl-oz',
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(disableCloudflareV1=True)
reviews_df = pd.DataFrame()
for x in tqdm(range(1, 12)):
    url = f'https://www.influenster.com/reviews/loreal-paris-elvive-extraordinary-oil-deep-nourishing-shampoo-and-conditioner-set-126-fl-oz?paginate=true&review_page={x}&sort=featured'

    r = scraper.get(url, headers=headers)
    df = pd.DataFrame(r.json()['items'])
    reviews_df = pd.concat([reviews_df, df], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
print(reviews_df)
```

Result in terminal:

```
id  stars   like_count  got_from_influenster    user_liked  timestamp   author  badge   text    media   merchant    product varieties   incentivized    comment_count   user_profile_questions  share_links
0   78801375    5   55  False   False   2021-07-09 20:42:45.554925+00:00    {'id': 8354487, 'username': 'genesist19', 'sho...   None    ☑️ I really like the products that come in Kit...   [{'id': 78801376, 'comment_count': 0, 'text': ...   None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
1   75217735    5   31  False   False   2021-03-03 14:41:18.119159+00:00    {'id': 8825695, 'username': 'gina78', 'short_n...   None    <a href="https://www.influenster.com/reviews/l...   [{'id': 75217738, 'comment_count': 0, 'text': ...   Walmart {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
2   81276486    5   26  False   False   2021-10-28 06:49:49.490998+00:00    {'id': 9540955, 'username': 'ayas30', 'short_n...   None    I really trust this brand, I alway purchase th...   []  Rite Aid    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
3   77920545    5   20  False   False   2021-06-08 03:50:20.528189+00:00    {'id': 9037996, 'username': 'member-dee631', '...   None    it was amazing it made me glow like the sun wa...   [{'id': 77920550, 'comment_count': 1, 'text': ...   None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
4   71949054    5   14  False   False   2020-11-19 20:57:11.267771+00:00    {'id': 8502511, 'username': 'gaiam12', 'short_...   None    Hi ! The second step of my routine hair and t...  [{'id': 71949055, 'comment_count': 1, 'text': ...   None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
99  68265871    4   0   False   False   2020-07-26 20:59:20.188833+00:00    {'id': 6556087, 'username': 'rosalbaee', 'shor...   None    It works wonders on my hair, leaves it soft, m...   []  None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
100 65351527    4   0   False   False   2020-05-23 09:45:58.051263+00:00    {'id': 1533122, 'username': 'normacastillo1de9...   None    I honestly expected amazing results from this ...   []  None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
101 63676384    4   0   False   False   2020-04-24 11:57:47.607444+00:00    {'id': 4863921, 'username': 'mary04', 'short_n...   None    Works great even for my oily hair. The conditi...   []  None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
102 57888332    4   0   False   False   2019-12-28 17:39:38.073223+00:00    {'id': 6899969, 'username': 'happinessonlyzone...   None    The product leaves my natural afro feeling sof...   []  None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
103 44909917    5   0   False   False   2018-12-26 14:27:44.321138+00:00    {'id': 4427462, 'username': 'stephaniea13', 's...   None    have natural curly and ringlety hair which is ...   [{'id': 44909920, 'comment_count': 0, 'text': ...   None    {'id': 3598670, 'name': 'LOréal Paris Elvive E...   []  None    0   []  {'Facebook': 'https://www.facebook.com/sharer/...
```

For tqdm, please visit https://pypi.org/project/tqdm/

For cloudscraper: https://pypi.org/project/cloudscraper/

For pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html

Comment: I want the stars in the reviews section only (ignoring the Q& A section and other star sections)

Comment: I ..  just gave you a solution for that. The dataframe contains `stars` column, with stars for each review. @Siyanarang

Comment: I want the answer to be given n my format and not the data frame format. This snippet is messing up with my already written code

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus I just noticed your commands on the other post, nicely answered!

Comment: good luck then @Siyanarang

Comment: @Siyanarang Siya narang, as far as the problem being in pandas, you can always query the data from pandas, check how to do so in https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus Good try explaining, +1 for the working solution.

Comment: TY @Warkaz, but I cannot help feeling this is a lost cause. I will leave the answer, maybe it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Try class names

full start: sc-gipzik ibaoTy

half star: sc-gipzik iSlZLl

but this could change at any given time. Probably a way to block scraping ;)